# Why I am getting error in Android while inserting data using endpoints of Google App Engile?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am accessing endpoints from android project. The App Engine Project has been deployed successfully.

**Here is my Android code:**

```
Usermasterendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new 

Usermasterendpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),

           new JacksonFactory(),

           new HttpRequestInitializer() {

           public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }

           });


            Usermasterendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(

        endpointBuilder).build();


            System.out.println("End of Asynk Task is...................///////////");

        try {

           UserMaster userManager = new UserMaster();//.setDescription("Note Description");

           String userID = new Date().toString();

           userManager.setUserID(userID);

           userManager.setEmail(Email);

           userManager.setUsername(username);

           userManager.setPassword(password);

           UserMaster UsermanagerResult = endpoint.insertUserMaster(userManager).execute();
```

**Here is my UserMaster entity class. Which I am trying to use from above android code.**

```
package com.jay.myapp.dao;


//********************************************************************************************************* 
//Author - Jay
//Description - This class is Data Access Object (DAO) for UserMasterDao entity
//        - Class is basically business class and mostly related to GAE/web application
//*********************************************************************************************************

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
import com.jagdish.mydprapp.model.UserMaster;
import com.jagdish.mydprapp.model.EMF;

public enum UserMasterDao {

    INSTANCE;

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UserMasterDao.class.getName());

//*****************************************************************************************************
//getUserByUsermasterID - This method will return List of users or user by getUserByUsermasterID
//*****************************************************************************************************

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //Suppress warning for getResultList()
public List<UserMaster> getUserByUsermasterID(Long usermasterID) {

log.info("Inside getUserByUsermasterID");  
EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
// Read the existing entries
Query q = em.createQuery("select t from UserMaster t where t.usermasterID = :usermasterID");
q.setParameter("usermasterID", usermasterID);
List<UserMaster> userlist = q.getResultList();
log.info("returning userlist");

return userlist;

}

//*****************************************************************************************************
//addUser - This method will add User to 
//*****************************************************************************************************

public void addUser(String userID, String employeeID, String mediamasterID, User user,
          String username, String password, String passwordhintquestion, String passwordhintanswer,
          String firstname, String lastname, String email, Long primaryphone, Long secondaryphone,
          Long primarymobile, Long secondarymobile, String gender, Long birthdate,
          String registrationID, String paypalID, String creditcardname, String creditcardnumber,
          String creditcardexpiration, String creditcardcvccode, String creditcardtype,
          boolean activeflag, String updatedby, String dateadded, String dateupdated, String comments) {

      synchronized (this) {
          log.info("Inside addUser");
          EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();

          //get current date time
          Date date = new Date();
          SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
          String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);


          //using user1 object variable instead of user - conflict issue with constructor 
          UserMaster user1 = new UserMaster(userID,  employeeID,  mediamasterID, user,
                  username,  password,  passwordhintquestion,  passwordhintanswer,
                  firstname,  lastname,  email,  primaryphone,  secondaryphone,
                  primarymobile,  secondarymobile,  gender,  birthdate,
                  registrationID,  paypalID,  creditcardname,  creditcardnumber,
                  creditcardexpiration,  creditcardcvccode,  creditcardtype,
                  activeflag,  updatedby,  formattedDate,  formattedDate,  comments);

          em.persist(user1);
          em.close();
          log.info("User added to UserMaster" + user1);
      }
}


//*****************************************************************************************************
// createDefaultUser
//*****************************************************************************************************

public void createDefaultUser(User user, UserMaster appUser, GenericDao<UserMaster> userDao) {

    //get current date time
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);

    log.info("current date time " + formattedDate);

    appUser = new UserMaster(user.getUserId(),"na","na",user, "na","na",
            "na", "na", user.getNickname(), "na", user.getEmail(), 0L, 0L,
          0L, 0L, "na", 0L, "na", user.getEmail(), "na", "na",
          "na", "na", "na", true, user.getUserId(), formattedDate, formattedDate, "na");

    userDao.put(appUser);

}




//*****************************************************************************************************
//removeUser - This method will remove User from table
//*****************************************************************************************************

public void removeUser(Long usermasterID) {
EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
try {
    log.info("Inside removeUser");
    UserMaster user = em.find(UserMaster.class, usermasterID);
    em.remove(user);
    log.info("User entry deleted");
} finally {
 em.close();
}
}



} //end of class
```

**Check the error I am getting:**

```
09-04 14:42:55.946: W/System.err(1603): 

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable

09-04 14:42:55.946: W/System.err(1603): {

09-04 14:42:55.946: W/System.err(1603):   "code" : 503,

09-04 14:42:55.946: W/System.err(1603):   "errors" : [ {

09-04 14:42:55.946: W/System.err(1603):     "domain" : "global",
09-04 14:42:55.956: W/System.err(1603):     "message" : "java.lang.NullPointerException",
09-04 14:42:55.956: W/System.err(1603):     "reason" : "backendError"
09-04 14:42:55.956: W/System.err(1603):   } ],
09-04 14:42:55.956: W/System.err(1603):   "message" : "java.lang.NullPointerException"
09-04 14:42:55.956: W/System.err(1603): }
09-04 14:42:55.956: W/System.err(1603):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:111)
09-04 14:42:55.956: W/System.err(1603):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:38)
09-04 14:42:55.986: W/System.err(1603):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
09-04 14:42:55.986: W/System.err(1603):     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1042)
09-04 14:42:55.986: W/System.err(1603):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
09-04 14:42:55.986: W/System.err(1603):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
09-04 14:42:55.986: W/System.err(1603):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
09-04 14:42:55.996: W/System.err(1603):     at com.jagdish.mydprapp.model.UserManagerAccessorClass.doInBackground(UserManagerAccessorClass.java:57)
09-04 14:42:55.996: W/System.err(1603):     at com.jagdish.mydprapp.model.UserManagerAccessorClass.doInBackground(UserManagerAccessorClass.java:1)
09-04 14:42:56.007: W/System.err(1603):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-04 14:42:56.026: W/System.err(1603):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-04 14:42:56.026: W/System.err(1603):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-04 14:42:56.037: W/System.err(1603):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-04 14:42:56.037: W/System.err(1603):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-04 14:42:56.046: W/System.err(1603):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Please help me to sort out the this issue. 
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

I got the answer you have to check weather auto generated id is null or not. It was giving me null first time. Just i have to add one if statement in my endpoint class in App engine project. in endpoint class you will get

```
containsYourEntityClass(YourEntityClass xyz) .
```

You have to add

```
if(YourEntityClass.getxxxID() == null)
                return false;
```

The whole code is

```
private boolean containsYourEntityClass(YourEntityClass xyz) {
        EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
        boolean contains = true;
        try {
            if(xyz.getxxxID() == null)
                return false;
            YourEntityClass item = mgr.find(YourEntityClass.class,
                    xyz.getxxxID());
            if (item == null) {
                contains = false;
            }
        } finally {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return contains;
    }
```